# Right it can be specified as the value of the text anchor attribute?

Tags: svg, d3.js

**This d3 code is correct?**

```
   .attr("text-anchor", "right")
```

Possible values, start, middle, end only?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor

Did you mean right is, d3 own specifications?

Comment: Not sure what your question is -- you've already found the reference that tells you that you can't use `right` and what the allowed values are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're right.The documentaion shows only three properties start, mid and end. Again you have many options to change the direction or position of the text.

1)

```
.style("text-anchor","mid") // you can change to start, end
            .attr("startOffset","50%") //you can change the percentage of offset
            .text("Your Text");
```

2)there is a property "Text Direction" in style

```
.style("direction","rtl") //where rtl stands for right to left
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for answers.
Over it became a reference